# How to correctly pop views in ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have this flow:
UITableView **foo** -> detail UIView **bar** containing another UITableView foo_1 -> detail UIView **bar_1**

The first UITableView foo contains a list of thing and leads to a detail UIView bar that contains another UITableView foo_1 that leads to another UIView bar_1 containing more details. 
Now, i have several buttons on the main app tabbar, and i can change view using it. When i tap a button leading to another view and then tap the button supposed to lead back to my UITableView foo, i am presented with foo, bar or bar_1, depending on which view i was, the last time i used the flow i described, but i want to go back to **foo** every single time i tap the corresponding button on the tabbar.

I supposed the right way to do this was by:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

but i am not sure where to use this code... I tried putting it in **bar_1** but it results in a "nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.". The result is a navigation bar getting mad and showing itself empty... 
So what is the correct way to go back in a similar situation?

Comment: Use view controllers and appropriately target your segues for the buttons. It sounds a lot like you're using a single view controller and adding more and more views to it...

Comment: Oh no, i am not. Sorry, it is difficult to explain. foo is a view controller containing only a uitableview. bar is a view controller containing some stuff and a uitableview (foo_1) . bar_1 is a view controller containing some stuff. I'm talking about three different view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward way would be to have a delegate for your `UITabBarController` and put your code inside the [`tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) method, which gets called every time the active tab is switched. Of course, you should check if it's the right view controller to not pop to the root one every tab switch.

Comment: i have the delegate in my AppDelegate.m and i have the method you're talking about. I am not really sure of what you mean by "check the index" and how to replace self with an appropriate reference to my foo controller... I tried to put there the 'popping' code and replace 'self' with 'viewcontroller' (the variable passed as argument to didselectViewController) but it doesn't seem to work. I thought this had almost to pop every time you tap the tabbar (that is not totally right, but i was just an experiment) but it seems not to work, ever

Comment: Ok, sorry, my bad - for some reason I thought that the index of the selected view controller would be passed to the delegate method, not the view controller itself. I edited my answer.

Comment: I can only guess why it doesn't work for you, but I see two potential pitfalls: 1) Make sure that you set the delegate; 2) Be aware that the view controller that is passed to `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` is already the `UINavigationController`, so you'd want to do `[viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]`.

Comment: I was so sure to have the delegate set, that... it wasn't! In the end, setting the delegate (tabBarController.delegate=self; in my appdelegate.m in function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) and popping with a simple popViewControllerAnimated inside bar and bar_1 views (the details) was enough to get the result i was searching for. Thank you very much!